# How to calculate voltage drop on lead acid battery

Tags: voltage, batteries, lead-acid

I have a motorcycle with an alarm on it.

I left the bike for 5 days and the battery dropped from 12.5v to 11.9v a 0.6v drop. The bike still started.

12 V battery 9.5 Ah sealed lead acid battery

I would like to calculate how long it would take to drop to 11 V or any other voltage for that matter so I know how long it can be left without charging it and still be able to start.

I think the alarm takes 0.005 amps, but I am sure this can be worked out from the information given.

Comment: If your sealed battery doesn't include any caps you can pop off (some no-maintenance batteries still do include them), then you probably cannot use the most accurate means -- a hydrometer. A simple voltage measurement for a fresh battery can be used. But the variations in voltage are small, so you'd want a way to "magnify" that small range. The "good way" for testing it is more involved. But none of these tell you "how long" because they don't know your usage and a 100 lb battery looks about the same as a 10 lb battery from most of the usual tests.

Comment: You could just cheat, though. Learn your battery. Take measurements (unloaded voltage, loaded voltage, voltage under high charging current, or whatever else you like) and log them in a book. Eventually, you'll have all the info you need for that particular battery. Keep the table with the battery. Make measurements when you wonder about the state and compare it to your table.

Answer (score 0):

There are too many variables to have any certainty, but you are already 50 % SoC at 12.5V and near 0% at 11.5V , and 100% at 12.5V after equalization time / quick load.  So it is unlikely to start in 10 days, but possible. There are 2nd order effects.

10day =240h *5mA = 1.24 Ah .. /9.5 = 13% is a bit high.  It should be possible to make that in << 0.5mA easily.  So if the other 40% loss in charge is due to leakage, that indicates some aging issues from contaminants.

The critical unknown is the rise in ESR as it approaches 11.5V as well as drop in C.

If you wanted to learn, perform a pulse test to measure ESR and C of battery.  If you wanted extended life don't let the voltage drop below 11.6 very long as that along with high ambient temp accelerates sulphation.  If you wanted to extend capacity, get a good battery pulse rejuvenator that operates when engine is running only.

Comment: Thanks for answering but you do not need to over complicate it. It isn't for a low tolerance science project so absolute accuracy is not needed. It's just how long can I leave the bike until I will have to charge it. The answer I have is: If it continued to drop 0.12v a day (0.6v over 5 days).
For 12.5v - 11v = 1.5v drop. 1.5/0.12 = 12.5 days until it gets to 11v. Whether it would start at 11v would be hit and miss depending on if it had been hot or cold weather. If there is not enough charge to use the starter motor then it should have enough voltage to run the ECU to be bump/push started.